# While enableProguardInReleaseBuilds is true ,build failed

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to reduce my react native apk size and I found a solution on here (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#enabling-proguard-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-apk-optional). However when I set enableProguardInReleaseBuilds true, I get an error during build. How can I fix that problem ? Or is there any solution for reduce react native apk size ?

In additon to that my app is starter app. So just write Hello World.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @GauravRoy startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57

Comment: please post the whole error  above in your  question

Comment: @GauravRoy Thank you I solved the problem. I will Share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a low level it means your version of Java is incompatible with the one with which Gradle was compiled. If you're using Java 13, you could try and install and set as default Java 11.

I have replace jdk13 with jdk11 and it works well.